# Extract Listbox's binded textblock to string wp7

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, listbox

I have a listbox with multiple binded textblocks. Is there a way that I can get binding textblock data from the selected listboxitem to an other page as a string?

```
<ListBox Margin="0,10,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Width="408" x:Name="ListBox1">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,17" Tap="StackPanel_Tap">
                            <!--Replace rectangle with image-->
                            <Rectangle Height="100" Width="100" Margin="12,0,9,0">
                                <Rectangle.Fill>
                                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding LineImg}" x:Name="img"/>
                                </Rectangle.Fill>
                            </Rectangle>
                            <StackPanel Width="311">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="title" Text="{Binding LineOne}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="30"/>
                                <Line X1="0" Y1="0" X2="1" Y2="0" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="White" />
                                <TextBlock x:Name="time" Text="{Binding LineTwo}" Margin="0,0,12,10" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                                <Image Height="20" Width="20" Margin="-170,-45,0,0" Source="/PostDateIcon.png"/>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="date" Text="{Binding LineThree}" Margin="85,-37,12,10" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="content" Text="{Binding LineContent}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                            </StackPanel>                            </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

I used this methode to load the binding data: http://kevinashley.com/connect-windows-phone-7-apps-to-wordpress-using-json/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this:

```
var yourClassName = ListBox1.SelectedItem as YourClassType;
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(String.Format("/TargetPage.xaml?param={0}", yourClassName.LineOne),  UriKind.Relative));
```

by this way,we can transition LineOne to your target page.